# Insert inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am writing an insert statement inside a stored procedure. When I am inserting duplicate value for SKU, I am not getting

> Error occurred while trying to insert the ProductPrice table

and `@errValue`.

I don't know why? It's just saying statement terminated

```
ALTER PROCEDURE HW5INS1
    -- PRODUCTPRICE TABLE: LEVEL-1
    @SKU VARCHAR(64),
    @startDate DATE,
    @endDate DATE = NULL,---NOT REQUIRED
    @price SMALLMONEY
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    -- Test For Existence Of Parent Row: LOOK INTO PRODUCTS TABLE
    IF EXISTS (SELECT SKU FROM Products WHERE SKU = @SKU)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ProductPrices (SKU, startDate, endDate, price)
        VALUES (@SKU, @startDate, @endDate, @price)

        SELECT * FROM ProductPrices

        DECLARE @errValue INT
        SET @errValue = @@ERROR

        IF (@@ERROR <>0)
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Error occurred while trying to insert the ProductPrice table'
            PRINT @errValue
            RETURN -11001
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- PARENT DOES NOT EXIST, RETURN ERROR
        PRINT 'Error: PARENT DOESNOT EXIST'
        RETURN -11002
    END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    RETURN
```

Comment: That error is a custom error and doesn't actually tell us the problem. What is the real error that is occurring?

Comment: Try `IF @errValue <> 0` instead of 'IF (@@ERROR <>0)'. @@ERROR is set after each statement.

Comment: I want  the query to return
              Error Occured While Trying To Insert The ProductPrice Table  and also
             PRINT @errValue however it is just saying duplicate key value and statement terminated without printing anything.

Comment: On a side note,  normally you would use a transaction like that within a `TRY...CATCH`. your `COMMIT` is at the end of the SP, so in the event of an error will never be reached, but you you don't have a `ROLLBACK`. That might cause you some problems.

Comment: @DanGuzman its still not displaying

Comment: @Larnu I added rollback transaction however error not printing for duplicate value.

Comment: From [`@@Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): "Because @@ERROR is cleared and reset on each statement executed, check it immediately following the statement being verified, or save it to a local variable that can be checked later." You're a bit lazy about picking up the value after the `insert`. And the `select`.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

You are trying to replicate database functionality in a stored procedure.  This is a bad idea.  One is that -- due to race conditions -- you cannot do as well as the database.  Second is that you might get this code right, but other code might update/insert/delete rows and cause problems.

The two things you want are a foreign key constraint and a unique constraint:

```
alter table ProductPrices add constraint fk_productprices_sku
    foreign key (sku) reference products(sku);

alter table ProductPrices add constraint unq_productprices_sku
    unique (sku);
```

You can capture the errors to rename them.  That seems like superfluous effort (in my opinion).  Just give the constrains meaningful names and let the database do its work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite your SP this way.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE HW5INS1

------PRODUCTPRICE TABLE: LEVEL-1
    @SKU varchar(64),
    @startDate date,
    @endDate date = NULL,---NOT REQUIRED
    @price smallmoney
AS


---------Test For Existence Of Parent Row: LOOK INTO PRODUCTS TABLE
If Exists(Select SKU from Products where SKU = @SKU)
      BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION
begin try
         INSERT INTO ProductPrices (SKU, startDate, endDate, price)
VALUES (@SKU, @startDate, @endDate, @price)
commit
end try
begin catch
           --select * from ProductPrices
         DECLARE @errValue int
         SET @errValue=@@ERROR
rollback
         IF (@ERROR <>0)
           BEGIN
             PRINT 'Error Occured While Trying To Insert The ProductPrice Table'
             PRINT @errValue
             RETURN -11001
           END
end catch
      END
ELSE
  BEGIN
  -----PARENT DOESNOT EXIST, RETURN ERROR
    PRINT 'Error: PARENT DOESNOT EXIST'
    RETURN -11002
  END

RETURN
```

Comment: Error Occured While Trying To Insert The ProductPrice Table
2627
Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure HW5INS1, Line 7
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of
BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 5, current count = 0.                                I am getting this mismatch error also don't know why.

Comment: Try to restart SQL server.